# Proper rendering of Sphinx substitutions in httpdomain extension

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I am using [sphinxcontrib-httpdomain](http://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/) extension to write Sphinx documentation. This extension is able to generate a ['routing table'](http://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/http-routingtable.html) page which I defined like [this](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/issue/51/httpdomain-make-http-routing-table).
I also defined a substitution which I use in my docs:

```py
# conf.py
rst_epilog = """
.. |mongodb_icon| raw:: html

   <span class="icon-dbs-mongodb"></span>
"""
```

However, when I put this substitution in the [synopsis](http://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/#options) directive of HTTPDomain extension, it is rendered out as plain text...

```
.. http:post:: /companies/
   :synopsis: Some text whatever |mongodb_icon|
```

How can I force this page (routing table) to render out my substitutions properly?